# Форматирование списка Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, jira

Есть список полученный из `jira`:

```
print(lst)
[<JIRA Issue: key='JIR-3324', id='226973'>, <JIRA Issue: key='JIR-3241', id='226225'>, <JIRA Issue: key='JIR-3134', id='225531'>, <JIRA Issue: key='JIR-2982', id='224337'>]
```

Нужно получить список `['JIR-3324', 'JIR-3241', 'JIR-3134', 'JIR-2982']`.

Вывожу один элемент:

```
print(lst[1])
# JIR-3241
```

Все вроде ок. Вывожу все элементы:

```
print(lst[1:])
[<JIRA Issue: key='JIR-3324', id='226973'>, <JIRA Issue: key='JIR-3241', id='226225'>, <JIRA Issue: key='JIR-3134', id='225531'>, <JIRA Issue: key='JIR-2982', id='224337'>]
```

снова лишняя информация :(

Делаю цикл:

```
for i in lst:
    print(i)
# JIR-3324
# JIR-3241
# JIR-3134
# JIR-2982
```

Все вроде отлично. Но для дальнейшей обработки нужен список. Ок, делаем так:

```
for i in lst:
    num = []
    num.append(i)
print(num)
[<JIRA Issue: key='JIR-2982', id='224337'>]
```

Снова лишняя информация и всего один элемент.

Пожалуйста объясните почему такой вывод и как правильно сделать список `['JIR-3324', 'JIR-3241', 'JIR-3134', 'JIR-2982']`?

Comment: «почему такой вывод» — потому что почитайте в учебнике по Python про классы, объекты, `__str__` и `__repr__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В списке у вас хранится сложный объект, у него есть поля. И одно из полей хранит номер задачи, вот и вытащите ее.

Попробуйте:

```
print([jira.key for jira in lst])
```

---

**PS.**

Кст, за то, чтобы тот объект показывал ту информацию вида `<JIRA Issue: key='JIR-3324', id='226973'>` и `JIR-3324` отвечают магические методы класса [**str**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) и [**repr**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) (их можно вызвать через встроенные функции `str` и `repr`).

И судя по тому что у вас в консоли пишет, то выходит, что у того объекта в `__repr__` выдается строка вида `<JIRA Issue: key='JIR-3324', id='226973'>`, а в `__str__` просто номер джиры. Поэтому, у вас по разному выглядело

Comment: Спасибо, отлично работает!
['JIR-3324', JIR-3241', 'JIR-3134', 'JIR-2982']

Comment: @Summoner, если помогло, то [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
num = []
for i in lst:
    num.append(i.key)
print(num)
```

Comment: Спасибо! .key работает! Это я насчет обнуления списка в цикле погорячился, но суть вы поняли. 
Спасибо.